# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'" when dividing two arrays element-wise

Tags: python, attributes, division, python-3.3, nonetype

I want to divide two one-dimensional arrays element-wise. There will be divisions by zero, but I still want to do the division. The result of div/0 is irrelevant, I'll handle that later.

Why does this error occur? And why does it stop occurring after I have checked the values of my arrays? How can I avoid this error when running my code?

```
>>> a=numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0])
>>> b=numpy.array([5, 3, 1, 0, 0])
>>> a/b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#57>", line 1, in <module>
    a/b
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 60, in idle_showwarning
    file.write(warnings.formatwarning(message, category, filename,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0])
>>> b
array([5, 3, 1, 0, 0])
>>> a/b
array([ 0.2       ,  0.66666667,  3.        ,         nan,         nan])
```

Comment: It looks like it's happening in IDLE -- If you put the code in a script, do you still have that problem?

Comment: Yes, it happens there as well.

Comment: Did you run the script from the commandline not from inside IDLE?

Comment: I have run the script in IDLE, but not in command line. Sorry, if I have misunderstood.

Comment: I don't get that error while running Python in `cmd`. Just a Warning of a ZeroDivision. Which Python Version are you using? I don't seem to get it in the IDLE for 2.7.3.

Comment: I'm running Python 3.3.2.

Comment: Looks like you found a bug in IDLE.

Comment: Yup. The Error Showing is done well in the 2.7.3 version. Something went wrong while porting it.

Comment: I circumvented this problem by changing "a/b" to "a/(b+(b==0))". Is this a confirmed bug? Should I make a bug report somewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write' error with scikit-learn digits dataset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139658/how-do-i-resolve-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-write-error-with-scikit-le)