# Why is my getpass.getpass() not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I'm relatively new to Python, but I've searched for answers on this. My code is:

```
import urllib, http
import gspread
import datetime
import getpass
import sys
from http import cookiejar

pwd = getpass.getpass()
```

and then obviously a lot more, but it throws me an error right at line 8:

```
File "C:\Python33\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 60, in idle_showwarning
    file.write(warnings.formatwarning(message, category, filename,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'"
```

I'm not sure if it matters, but this is what I'm using the pwd for:

```
payload = {
  'op': 'login-main',
  'SignonAccountNumber': '###',
  'SignonPassword': pwd
  }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write' error with scikit-learn digits dataset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139658/how-do-i-resolve-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-write-error-with-scikit-le)

Comment: Have you tried executing your script directly from the command line rather than from idle?

Comment: It was an idle problem - thanks for your help. I have no idea how to 'upvote' your comments, though

Comment: This bug was fixed sometime before 2.7.13 and 3.5.3, which are the earliest I have loaded to test on.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IDLE as your editor then your issue may be this bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue18030

In the bug report, the user gets around the issue by running IDLE with this command: python -m idlelib.idle