# Don't understand why debugging a script in VS Code is causing an AttributeError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, attributeerror, nonetype

I'm new to python, been learning it for the past few weeks. I recently started getting the following error when debugging a Python script in VS Code:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
  File "C:\SW-Languages\__LEARNING\Learning Python\Ex_Files_Learning_Python\Exercise Files\Ch3\itertoolsPermutations.py", line 8, in <module>
    print("Hello")
```

Here is the code (originally was more, but isolated it to this simple 1 line program:

```
print("Hello")
```

I installed VS Code from Anaconda, everything worked fine for the first couple of weeks, then I made an updates to anaconda (I don't recall details) and also installed new Python packages when the error first occurred.

The "Hello" script works fine when executed from a command shell (as do all my other python scripts, but basically I can only use VS Code for editing, none of my scripts will run in VS Code now, I have to execute them via a cmd shell.

Additional info:

from cmd shell:

```
C:\Users\jd400>python -VV

Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)]
```

from VS Code terminal:

```
(base) PS C:\SW-Languages\__LEARNING\wxFormBuilder\wx-Widget-Examples\sc> python -VV

Python 3.7.2 (default, Feb 21 2019, 16:05:07) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

I have researched the following related posts on stackoverflow, but they were no help:

[How do I resolve 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write' error with scikit-learn digits dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139658/how-do-i-resolve-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-write-error-with-scikit-le)

[AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595337/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-write)

[Don't understand what this AttributeError means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/dont-understand-what-this-attributeerror-means)

Comment: You do not execute a 1-line program and get that error message: `print("Hello")` works. Please post a [mcve] that lets us reproduce your error.

Comment: Sorry but the entire program consists of 1 line: print ("Hello") and nothing else. The original code had more, but I commented out all but the print statement. In fact, I just created a new script with a one line print statement and still get the same error :

Comment: Your error is in `C:\SW-Languages\__LEARNING\Learning Python\Ex_Files_Learning_Python\Exercise Files\Ch3\itertoolsPermutations.py` wich at least contains 8 lines according to the error message. You other program with print("hello") has nothing to do with it. Copy & paste your program into an online IDE - f.e. http://pyfiddle.io - put it to python 3.x and execute it there.

Comment: Yes line 8 is this: "print("Hello")" - print statements used to work, but are no longer working in VS Code. But when I execute this script from a cmd shell it works fine.

Comment: My issue is with VS Code, I can no longer debug in it. Print statements no longer work as mentioned above. Print statements cause this exception: Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: You have two different versions of Python 3.7 installed on your system. One in a 32-bit Python 3.7.0 and the other that VS Code is using is 64-bit Python 3.7.2. It quite possible that some extensions that work in one don't work in the other—so I suggest fix that issue by getting rid of one of them. Also, FWIW, one way that `print()` calls could producean ` AttributeError` like that is if `sys.stdout` has somehow been set to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after doing more research on the web -

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3272
Simple print command not working #3272

The solution is to change python executable in settings.json from:
  ...\Anaconda3\python**w**.exe",
to
  ...\Anaconda3\python.exe",

I appreciate the suggestions others have made in solving my issue and even though it's now solved, I still may get rid of the other installed version of python as martineau suggested to make things cleaner.